# Why couldn't Octavian (Tavi) manifest a fury sooner?

Tags: jim-butcher, codex-alera

Octavian starts to be able to internalize furies about 5 years after leaving his valley. However it's 2 more years until he is actually able to manifest a fury of his own.

In a conversation between Marcus and the First Lord it's said that the First Lord's son manifested a fury at 5 years old and burnt down his nursery. So why did Tavi struggle for so much longer to manifest a fury?

Comment: Did it really say he manifested a fury at that point, or just that he came into his powers at that point?  They're two different things.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the exact passage is "How old was Septimus when he started crafting?" Gaius shrugged. "About five, I think. He set the nursery on fire. Why?" As far as I know to set something on fire you have to manifest a fire fury. All we ever see internalized fire crafting used for is to warm up one's own body when they are cold.

Comment: My recollection is that manifestation is only required for advanced furycrafting techniques, not for something as simple as setting fire to something.  I'll have another look when I get time and, if I think the text supports my position, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the place to look is most likely in the 3rd book when Max's step-mom is interrogating Tavi and asks him to start a fire. Also, support the under valued universes and upvote! :)

Answer (score 3):

An insane amount of learning goes on while you're a kid.

Septimus grew into his inherited fury power naturally.  For the Alerans it seems to be a natural part of childhood, instinct coming first and power and control coming with time (although most aren't powerful enough to set fires at age 5).

Octavian labored for *fifteen years* under not only the block that prevented him from doing anything of the sort, but also the very well reinforced illusion that he would never be able to call on any power (that held for years further).  He never had the chance to grow into it naturally.  He'd have no developed sense of what the furies would feel like, no mental muscle for the will required to shape them.  The rest of his mind and body would have grown on without it.  It'd be like a limb that had hung uselessly all his life, that just started to twitch; it'd be a wonderful healing, and you can try and push it and use it and eventually get just as strong with it, but it would never be like you suddenly had it all along.

Also notable, he still had to hide his developing powers afterwards for at least a few more years, he had nothing like a regular teacher for many years further, and his life didn't stop being interesting enough to just settle down and do nothing else but push his talent.  Any of the above would add to the delay before he was fully developed.

Answer (score 1):

The conversation you're referring to was in the final chapter of *Cursor's Fury*:

> "How old was Septimus when he started crafting?"
>
> Gaius shrugged.  "Above five, I think.  He set the nursery on fire.  Why?"

That does not, however, necessarily imply that Septimus manifested a fire fury at that age.  The prologue to *Captain's Fury* establishes that large bursts of fire require a manifestation, but you do not require a large burst of fire in order to start a fire in a nursery - a single spark will do.

In fact, from Chapter 9 of *Cursor's Fury*:

> "Now be a dear for me, Subtribune, and light this campfire?"
>
> Tavi felt his smile falter for a second.  "Beg pardon?"
>
> "The campfire, " Lady Antillus said, as though speaking to the village idiot.  "I think a herbal tea would be nice for all of us to enjoy if Maximus is up and about.  You've had your basic furycrafting.  I've seen your record.  So, Subtribune Scipio.  Light the campfire."

Compare to chapter 10 of *Captain's Fury*:

> Tavi's crafting was still sharply limited by his lack of ability to control a manifest fury, but had he been in the Academy, he would have earned two or three beads in every single branch of crafting by now.  While it was not unheard of for a crafter - especially a scion of the Citizenry - to be gifted in several areas of craft, it was exceedingly rare for anyone but the upper tiers of talent to possess skills that ran the entire spectrum of furycraft.

Most of the main characters, in fact, only have one or two furies: Amara has a wind fury, Isana a water fury, Berhard an earth and a wood fury.  If starting a fire required manifesting a fire fury, most people would be unable to do so.

Therefore, it would not be part of basic training, and Tavi's inability would not have been something that could give him away.  As Lady Antillus put it, only "some kind of freak with no crafting at all" would be unable to start a fire, which can only mean that it is *not* necessary to manifest a fury in order to do so.